# SELECT count mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a database called Real_Estate_Lab_Project, I have a table call listings, with a column named listing price.

```
listing_key int PK 
listing_status int 
listing_type int 
date_listed date 
date_expires date 
date_unlisted date 
reason_unlisted int 
address varchar(50) 
city varchar(30) 
state char(2) 
zip_code varchar(10) 
lot_number varchar(50) 
residential_area int 
listing_price int 
listing_agreement_signed_date date 
remark varchar(1000)
```

I am trying to run

```
USE Real_Estate_Lab_Project;

SELECT count(*) 
    as no_of_listings, 
    avg(price) as avg_listing_price, sum(listings) 
    as sum_of_listings, min(price) 
    as min_price, max(price) 
    as max_price 
from Listing 
where status = 'Active'
```

When I run script it is telling me

Error Code: 1146. Table 'real_estate_lab_project.listing' doesn't exist 0.000 sec, but I know it exists as I can see it when I do

```
SELECT * from listings.
```

The date expires column does have some that are expired, but some are not.

What am I missing?

Comment: Typo?  `as max_price from Listing` vs `SELECT * from listings.`  That's capitalized and pluralized vs not.

Comment: Could you share your tables (`SHOW TABLES FROM your_db`) and columns from the table `listings` (`SHOW COLUMNS FROM your_db.listings`)? Replace your_db with the name of your database.

Comment: `Listing` and `listings` are two different tables.

Answer (score 0):

it looks you have to replace 'Listing' with listings in your sql

```
SELECT count(*) 
    as no_of_listings, 
    avg(price) as avg_listing_price, sum(listings) 
    as sum_of_listings, min(price) 
    as min_price, max(price) 
    as max_price 
from listings
where status = 'Active
```

'

Comment: Went in and corrected a few things, now its throwing

Comment: 0 176 15:53:08 SELECT count(*) 
     as no_of_listing_price, 
     avg(listing_price) as avg_listing_price, sum(listing_price) 
     as sum_of_listings, min(listing_price) 
     as min_price, max(listing_price) 
     as max_price 
 from listings
 where status = 'Active'
Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'status' in 'where clause' 0.000 sec

Comment: Dont know how to edit the question fields or I would.

Comment: @rellimpg Which part of the error message is not clear???  It is obvious you don't have column `status` in your table.  Even in your table definition above, I don't see column `status`.

Comment: This is what I ended up with and it works, trying to figure out "2 decimal places now".     SELECT count(listing_status) 
    as no_of_listing_price, 
    avg(listing_price) as avg_listing_price, sum(listing_price) 
    as sum_of_listings, min(listing_price) 
    as min_price, max(listing_price) 
    as max_price 
from listings
WHERE listing_status = 1

Comment: Figured it out.  Learning SQL.